# Update frames button gone in Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, xcode8

After updating to 8.1 (8B62) there is no longer a button for updating frames in a storyboard/xib, in the Resolve Auto Layout Issues shortcut in the bottom right corner of the Interface Builder. I heard talk about putting such a button on the new and fancy touch bar, but what does this mean to a mere mortal like myself? Do I have to start using the menu bar?

Now:
[image]

Before:

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Update frames is a separate option now and not inside the drop down. I am on Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62) and I can see the below button:

[image]

It is enabled only if the control is misplaced

Comment: Would you look at that. Even better than before!

Comment: I have the same version of Xcode but the button is still disable even i misplaced the View.

Comment: @Mahesh did u select the control? You have to click on control and then the button becomes usable.

Comment: It usually doesn't work for me, but it might be because some of my constraints are >= so there isn't an obvious precise size even though I see the +/- red lines telling me the frame is off.