# I'm trying to fix my pins in XCode but not getting update frames button in XCode8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

[image: Main Storyboard image]

Hi. I'm building a simple calculator application but not getting Update Frame Option in Resolve Auto Layout issues. Is there anything that I'm not doing correctly? How to resolve the pins correctly in the layout?

Comment: Click on the clockwise arrow button in the bottom window border

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks.. Yes, Just found out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I found the solution later on another thread.
In case you are interested here is the thread: [Update frames button gone in Xcode 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351994/update-frames-button-gone-in-xcode-8-1)

And the answer is since XCode8.1 release, there is a new button altogether for Update frames on the farthest left in the same series as the Resolve Auto Layout option..

[image: Update Frames New Button]